# Run a SWF File with the terminal

Tags: flash, actionscript, terminal

Is there a way to run a swf file through the terminal? 
Like the `php -f file.php` function?

Comment: Why would you want to do that, except for unit testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of. You can open the Standalone Flash Player application and pass a swf file as an argument, something like:

```
path/to/your/standalone/FlashPlayer yourFile.swf
```

You might find [as3term](http://code.google.com/p/as3term/) interesting. If you look through the source code, you'll notice the compiled swf gets loaded, but not added to the display list, still, the whole application as it's root is a swf.

Note that you will always have a window open. For example, any Document/Main as3 class extends Sprite, which is a displayable object, kind of like extending Applet in Java - you will end up with something on screen. You can't execute a swf just as text like a typical command line application AFAIK.

Speaking of Java, [Joa Ebert's JITB](http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2010/08/19/introducing-jitb/) project is quite impressive. I'm not sure how feasible it is, but maybe it would be possible to use/modify the project to run actionscript bytecode without a GUI. Still, it doesn't look like something easy/straightforward. What exactly do you need done in actionscript that doesn't need an interface ? Maybe the same functionality can be achieved with a script you can run from the command line (like php,python, etc.) ?

Comment: i'll check these solutions later. i've managed to solve it in some other way. however, thanks for your respond!

Comment: Glad you've sorted it out. Would be nice to have the solution for documentation (if possible). Thanks !

Comment: Well, I've had to run a swf file like 3000 times. So I built an XML file with the data and made a `for each()` loop. It's not a "real" solution, you see? But it worked.

Answer (score -1):

`.swf` files can be opened on terminal by using **gnash** swf viewer.